# Silencing postgres log spam in rails 3 logs

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

On every request my development.log contains a lot of entries like so:

```
SQL (0.5ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
WHERE a.attrelid = '"table1"'::regclass
AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum

SQL (0.5ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
WHERE a.attrelid = '"table2"'::regclass
AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum
```

These are completely drowning out the log messages I actually care about.  Is there a good way to silence these extra messages?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add this to your Gemfile, do a `bundle install`, and restart your server.

```
gem "silent-postgres"
```