# How can I remove Postgres "PK and serial sequence" cruft from my logs?

Tags: postgresql, activerecord

I'm using ActiveRecord in a project with Postgres, and my logs are full of this log message. I'd like to keep the log file in debug mode while I'm developing. Is there a way I can silence this particular warning? I'm already using the `silent-postgres` gem to silence a bunch of other cruft (as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858797/silencing-postgres-log-spam-in-rails-3-logs) recommends, but it doesn't help this case). Thanks!

```
D, [2011-08-25T10:22:10.530123 #78199] DEBUG -- :   PK and serial sequence (1.7ms)   SELECT attr.attname, seq.relname
FROM pg_class seq,
pg_attribute attr,
pg_depend dep,
pg_namespace name,
pg_constraint cons
WHERE seq.oid = dep.objid
AND seq.relkind = 'S'
AND attr.attrelid = dep.refobjid
AND attr.attnum = dep.refobjsubid
AND attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid
AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
AND cons.contype = 'p'
AND dep.refobjid = '"calls"'::regclass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the silent-postgres gem did solve this problem.  Perhaps it's been enhanced after the OP asked the question?

Comment: I was able to silence it by changing the Postgres `min_messages` setting to `warning`, but your answer prompted me to go check out the gem which indeed has been updated. The new silent-postgres gem README includes a note explaining how to set this warning level at a database connection variable (https://github.com/dolzenko/silent-postgres/blob/master/README), so thanks for prompting me to go check!